# On the order of CUDA printf outputs

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda

I'm new to CUDA and I'm trying to do parallel printing with CUDA `printf`.

In my example below, I have `6` threads and `6` data arrays and I need to print all `6` arrays "at the same time" in CUDA. Each array should be assigned to `1` thread which will print it. I'm trying since more than a week and don't get it how to do it, because always I get results ordered in a row: first array printed first, second array printed second and etc. However, I would like to observe mixed printing, to prove "randomness" of the parallel executions. Here is my code:

```
no code
```

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a very tiny kernel containing only 1 block with 6 threads, all the threads runs in a warp. Within a warp, different threads have to wait each other.
Please refer to the programming guide for more details.

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#simt-architecture

> A warp executes one common instruction at a time, so full efficiency
>   is realized when all 32 threads of a warp agree on their execution
>   path. If threads of a warp diverge via a data-dependent conditional
>   branch, the warp serially executes each branch path taken, disabling
>   threads that are not on that path, and when all paths complete, the
>   threads converge back to the same execution path. Branch divergence
>   occurs only within a warp; different warps execute independently
>   regardless of whether they are executing common or disjoint code
>   paths.

As a result, your data will be printed out with the same order of your code (First `if(id==1){...}`, then `if(id==2){...}`, ...).

Comment: Yes if you use `Procesas<<<6,1>>>` and let `int id = blockIdx.x`. Then you may meet the flush issue mentioned in Jack's answer.

Comment: However printing text is a very bad way of using GPU

Comment: I know that is very bad way but it is task and I should do whatever I got :) Okay, `Procesas<<<6,1>>>` did the job, big thanks to you! But there is any way to print parallel with `1,6`, because  man who gave me this task, said that i should increase threads count, not blocks?

Comment: `<<<1,6*32>>>` may be able to do that, since a warp contains only 32 threads.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the CUDA C Programming Guide pp. 113-114: it provides some information on how `printf` flushes its output.

**EDIT**

Also according to Eric's answer, by `printf` you will see only a "granular" randomness, the randomness being related to the random nature of the warp execution. Everything is inside a warp can appear to be ordered.

Have also a look to this other thread

[CUDA : unexpected printf behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532220/cuda-unexpected-printf-behavior)

where Robert Crovella explains the logic behind CUDA `printf` outputs.

Comment: And what I need to change according to this to print in parallel? Sorry, but I didn't understand..

Comment: @Eddwhis There was too much unuseful information on my previous answer. I have edited the post to better focus on the problem.